# Mongoose virtual field on subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm have this schema:

```
const childSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   days: Number
})
const parentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   date: Date,
   children: [ childSchema ]
})
```

I need to get a virtual field called "date" in `childSchema` that calculates the date of the `parentSchema`, adding up the `childSchema`'s days.

```
childSchema.virtual('date').get(function(){
  // How can I get the parentSchema's data ?
})
```

Comment: how is parent related to child ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `children: [ childSchema ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `this.parent` method for the getter function to access the parent document.

```
childSchema.virtual('date').get(function(){
  const parent = this.parent();
});
```